# How to detect 5 second lasting touch event on Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to detect when user touches screen constantly for 5 seconds. No things like onLongTouch() are taken into consideration. Mechanism should be transparent, because I'm overriding onTouchEvent() to change Views in ViewFlipper.

Should I do it manually by creating new thread that would be timing a touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start a timer when the MotionEvent is MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and stop it when the event is MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.
This is the time the user had his finger on the screen (including dragging).
If you want to restart the timer on dragging, check for ACTION_MOVE and restart the timer. But I don't recommend doing that since these events might be thrown even if the user accedintly moved his hand very slightly while holding his finger down on the screen.

Comment: You could also set a threshold for ACTION_MOVE events, and ignore them until a certain frequency is met (i.e. the user is actually dragging)

Comment: Are you thinking about java `Timer` class?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself clearly.
Use System.currentTimeMillis() at the ACTION_DOWN to save the current time and check again on ACTION_UP.